# Input of pdf_tex error with usepackage{underscore} input

Tags: pdftex, input, underscore

i have a problem i now solved by myself. It took some days, so i want to pretend others to make the same fault.

I want to input a .pdf and .pdf_tex file from Inkscape into Latex an compile it with pdflatex. Therefore i use the \input command. But there is this erreor message:

> "! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> \unhbox
> l.15 \input{Belastungsart2.pdf_tex}? "

Here is the Code:

```
\documentclass[
            final               % Status des Dokuments (draft-> nur Rahmen der Bilder)
        ]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % T1 Schriftcodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % deutsche Silbentrennung einbinden
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % deutsche Umlaute erkennen und darstellen
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{underscore}                     %Unterstrich im Text als Unterstrich machen

\begin{document}

\input{Belastungsart2.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

The content of "Belastungsart2.pdf_tex" is this one:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{260.95278915bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.23962115)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0.49704523,0.1373812){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\sigma$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.59934306,0.14224841){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\gamma$\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.60374442,0.09517703){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}$\tau$\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Sorry, but I couldnt minimize the content of  the .pdf_tex file.
When i comment out the \usepackage{underscore} command, everything is working fine. No error message at all.
When i paste the content of Belastungsart.pdf_tex into the main-code everything is working fine.
When i rename the .pdf_tex file to an .tex file, everything is working fine.

Is there a way to use the package underscore and place the \input{.pdf_tex} in Latex at the same time?

Thanks for help
Nelson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is described in the [manual of the underscore package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/underscore/underscore.pdf).

You code contains the command `\input{Belastungsart2.pdf_tex}`. This command contains an underscore character, which causes the input to fail because the `underscore` package changes the interpretation of this character. As mentioned in the manual, it works if you explicitly state that this underscore is a literal underscore, using the `\string` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
            final               % Status des Dokuments (draft-> nur Rahmen der Bilder)
        ]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % T1 Schriftcodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             % deutsche Silbentrennung einbinden
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % deutsche Umlaute erkennen und darstellen
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{underscore}                     %Unterstrich im Text als Unterstrich machen

\begin{document}

\input{Belastungsart2.pdf\string_tex}
\end{document}
```

Another possible solution, also mentioned in the manual, is to use `\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`. With that option you can use underscores as normal in file names, so `\input{Belastungsart2.pdf_tex}` will work. However, this is more risky, because the option will modify a lot of internal code, which may cause other problems. Therefore, if you only have a few underscores for filenames etc, it is probably better to use the `\string` solution.

Comment: Thank you Marijn. That was a very fast answer. I also read the underscore-package manual afterwards, but I didnt get it.
Your first solution with ```\input{Belastungsart2.pdf\string_tex}``` works fine for me.
The ```\usepackage[string]{underscore}```-Soution create failures on my computer.

Comment: @Nelson maybe you forgot the `s` - it is `\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`, not `\usepackage[string]{underscore}` as you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Thats the point, thank you very much